# Chrome - CSS - Background-size overlapping

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background-image, background-size

I'm having trouble to overlap a background-image like this:

```css
div.test{
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red
}

div.container{  
  height: 480px;
  width: 150px;
  
}

div.test:before, div.test:after{
      content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

div.test:before{
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E5E5E5 1px, transparent 1px);
    background-size: 100% 15.0px;
}

div.test:after{
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 1px, transparent 1px);
    background-size: 100% 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">

  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to overlap the 4-nth stripe, but I don't understand why it is not working. The stripe gets more separated each time it repeats itself. If the "before" pseudoelement is repeating every 15px, shouldn't the "after" pseudo element be placed over the 4-nth stripe if it's height is exactly 60px?.

Edit: Just noticed this only happens in Chrome:

[image]

This is Firefox:

[image]

Comment: i don't see any problem in your code, except that you are using the same color for the "before" and "after", so that is "invisible" to the eye, i have change it to be more visible in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/351wpfgx/

Comment: I added an image of what Chrome is rendering, you can see that the blu eline is not lined to the white one. Its working fine in Firefox

Comment: Does the Stack Snippet in your question render the same way for you? It doesn't for me either. In fact, I don't see any blue at all in either browser.

Comment: I uploaded images of what i see, both in Chrome and Firefox. Firefox browser seems to display what is intended, but in Chrome I see a separation that gets bigger every time.

Comment: @BizTuk hmm, i'm using the latest chrome 64 bit for windows, it's displaying correctly, what is your version?, have you enable [page zoom](https://cnet2.cbsistatic.com/img/6bGJ1uantV22pphxn3in0L80dmM=/fit-in/370x0/2015/08/26/af7069ae-f379-4635-99a1-21e0acfe9753/chrome-zoom-settings.jpg) (displaying not at 100%)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it, strips are  displayed as you want(To check it I have updated the strip color only). what is the problem?

```css
div.test{
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red
}

div.container{  
  height: 480px;
  width: 150px;
  
}

div.test:before, div.test:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

div.test:before{
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E5E5E5 1px, transparent 1px);
    background-size: 100% 15.0px;
}

div.test:after{
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #007ac2 1px, transparent 1px);
    background-size: 100% 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my post with images of what gets rendered in both Chrome and Firefox, apparently its not working on Chrome for some reason.